# How to jointly model a binary outcome with an associated confidence rating using R?

Tags: r, logistic, mixed-model, joint-distribution, brms

I have data of the form:

| judgment | confidence | variable |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0.4 | 2 |
| A | 0.7 | 1 |
| A | 0.8 | 5 |
| B | 0.2 | 4 |
| B | 0.6 | 6 |
| B | 0.1 | 8 |

- Outcomes:

  - A **dichotomous** variable (binary judgment)
  - A **confidence score** associated with the judgment [0-100%]
- Predictors:

  - An **experimental** variable (continuous)

So far, I have been successful at modelling spearately the decision using **logistic** models (binomial family; `judgment ~  variable`) and the confidence depending on the judgment (`confidence ~ judgment / variable`) using beta regressions.

However, I feel like it would be better to model the decision and the confidence jointly, but I am not aware of any models / methods that would allow me to do that. Any pointers are welcome

Toy example:

```r
df <- data.frame(judgment = as.factor(c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B")),
                 confidence = c(0.3, 0.4, 0.2, 0.1, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7),
                 variable = c(1, 2.5, 1.5, 1, 3, 2, 4))

m1 <- glm(judgment ~ variable, data=df, family="binomial")
summary(m1)
#> 
#> Call:
#> glm(formula = judgment ~ variable, family = "binomial", data = df)
#> 
#> Deviance Residuals: 
#>       1        2        3        4        5        6        7  
#> -0.2831  -1.4078  -0.5144  -0.2831   0.5613   1.4919   0.1682  
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
#> (Intercept)   -5.680      4.040  -1.406    0.160
#> variable       2.483      1.779   1.396    0.163
#> 
#> (Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)
#> 
#>     Null deviance: 9.5607  on 6  degrees of freedom
#> Residual deviance: 4.9758  on 5  degrees of freedom
#> AIC: 8.9758
#> 
#> Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 5

m2 <- glmmTMB::glmmTMB(confidence ~ judgment / variable, data=df, family=glmmTMB::beta_family())
summary(m2)
#>  Family: beta  ( logit )
#> Formula:          confidence ~ judgment/variable
#> Data: df
#> 
#>      AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
#>     -6.6     -6.9      8.3    -16.6        2 
#> 
#> 
#> Dispersion parameter for beta family (): 34.6 
#> 
#> Conditional model:
#>                    Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
#> (Intercept)         -2.2584     0.5379  -4.199 2.69e-05 ***
#> judgmentB            2.0449     0.9128   2.240   0.0251 *  
#> judgmentA:variable   0.7285     0.3072   2.371   0.0177 *  
#> judgmentB:variable   0.2057     0.2379   0.865   0.3872    
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: How do your judgment and the confidence hang together? From your example, it looks like your judgment is A if and only if confidence exceeds 0.5. If so, it sounds like a regression on logits or a beta regression would make most sense.

Comment: Good catch, the example was misleading. I edited, but the confidence's range is [0-1] for both outcome (i.e., the judgment was not created by a dichotomous split of the confidence rating)